# Is it feasible to model a CMOS inverter as a control system?

Tags: digital-logic, control, control-system, cmos, inverting-amplifier

I have some knowledge of basic control theory from a course I took this summer and I'd like to use it to model CMOS circuits for an independent study project with one of my EE professors this upcoming semester.  Our project will focus on CMOS inverters and how their physical characteristics of the PN junctions (e.g. doping concentrations, semiconductor type) affect their switching speed and energy efficiency. We will also use Simulink to model some digital circuits with the parameters from the CMOS simulations.

My main question is: Is it reasonable to try to apply control theory to model CMOS inverters and design controllers that optimize their switching speed and energy efficiency?

- More specifically, can I model a CMOS inverter as a plant in a control system, with an input voltage source and an output block measuring the switching speed, and design a controller to keep the switching speed close to some target speed while also maintaining reasonable energy efficiency?
- I was thinking that it might make sense to try to design an LQG or LQR controller, since those are often used when there's a need to balance between possibly competing priorities.  Is this a reasonable approach?

To summarize: Is control theory the right set of tools for this sort of project? If not, what would be a more suitable approach?

Comment: I expect you can do this but, whether it meets your ultimate aims, it's unclear.